# Pandas: More Efficient Index Dump?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a Pandas DataFrame in the following format:

```
              rtt rexb
asn   country
12345 US      300 0.5
54321 US      150 0.2
12345 MX      160 0.15
```

I wish to dump two JSON files: one with a list of all countries for a given ASN and another with all ASNs for a given country:

```
country-by-asn.json:
{
    "12345": ["US", "MX"],
    "54321": ["US"]
}

asn-by-country.json:
{
    "US": ["12345", "54321"],
    "MX": ["54321"]
}
```

I'm currently doing the following:

```
asns = df.index.levels[0]
countries = df.index.levels[1]

country_by_asn = {}
asn_by_country = {}

for asn in asns:
    by_asn = df.loc[[d == asn for d in df.index.get_level_values("asn")]]
    country_by_asn[asn] = list(by_asn.index.get_level_values("country"))

for country in countries:
    by_country = df.loc[[d == country for d in df.index.get_level_values("country")]]
    asn_by_country[country] = list(by_country.index.get_level_values("asn"))
```

This works, but feels kind of clunky. Is there a more efficient (in terms of processing power, not necessarily in terms of code complexity) way to get the same output?

**Experimentally confirmed to be "clunky". Running on 68,000 rows of data took 435 seconds**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html) with `groupby`, convert values to `list` and last [`to_json`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.to_json.html): -- **Experimentally ran on 68,000 rows of data in 2.2 seconds**

```
df1 = df.reset_index()

a = df1.groupby('asn')['country'].apply(list).to_json()
b = df1.groupby('country')['asn'].apply(list).to_json()
```

Or pure python solution - first create list of tuples, then dictionary and last `json`: -- **Experimentally ran on 68,000 rows of data in 0.06 seconds**

```
import json

l = df.index.tolist()

a, b = {}, {}
for x, y in l:
    a.setdefault(x, []).append(y)
    b.setdefault(y, []).append(y)

a = json.dumps(a)
b = json.dumps(b)
```

Similar solution: -- **Experimentally ran on 68,000 rows of data in 0.06 seconds**

```
l = df.index.tolist()

from collections import defaultdict

a, b = defaultdict( list ), defaultdict( list )

for n,v in l:
    a[n].append(v)
    b[v].append(n)

a = json.dumps(a)
b = json.dumps(b)
```

@stevendesu's "newbie" solution: -- **Experimentally ran on 68,000 rows of data in 0.06 seconds**

```
l = df.index.tolist()

a, b = {}, {}

for n, v in l:
    if n not in a:
        a[n] = []
    if v not in b:
        b[v] = []
    a[n].append(v)
    b[v].append(n)

a = json.dumps(a)
b = json.dumps(b)
```

---

```
print (a)
{"12345": ["US", "MX"], "54321": ["US"]}

print (b)
{"MX": [12345], "US": [12345, 54321]}
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggested solutions. Before end of day I'll run a quick performance test with each of your solutions (compared to mine) and see how fast they run.

Comment: @pyd - I come late, I think pir or another answer is what you need.

Comment: I am yet to test with my data, ill accept it once I tested jezrael, sorry for delay

Comment: @pyd - I think you forget ;) It is absolutely OK ;) Nice day!

Comment: Took a while to find time for the testing. Using my real data (48,000 ASNs and 200 countries) I just measured the run time for now. I'll check the accuracy of the data (starting with the fastest method) next: **My method**: 435 seconds, **groupby**: 2.23 seconds, **"pure python"**: 0.06 seconds, **"similar"**: 0.06 seconds

Comment: I started with the accuracy of the "similar" solution (it was the same speed as the "pure python" solution but the code made a bit more sense to me at first glance) and the output looks correct! Thank you

Comment: One small tweak: As a test I tried replacing `defaultdict(list)` with a standard `{}` and adding `if n not in a: a[n] = []` (and similar for `b`). This had an identical run-time but the code is a bit more newbie-friendly :)

Comment: @stevendesu - thank you for experience of your test. Be free modify my answer with your another solution, because now  I am only on phone. Thanks.